# contactTestBitMask for nil Physicsbodies

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision, skphysicsbody

Will `contactTestBitMask` still work if both `SKPhysicsBodies` involved are not dynamic? This is in swift using `SpriteKit`.

Comment: No, one of the physics bodies needs to be dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the contact test bitmask will work regardless of whether one body is dynamic. Keep in mind that just because the body has dynamic set to NO does not mean that the body itself is nil.

Edit - just realized you wanted to know if BOTH are non-dynamic. this won't work since sprite-kit won't create a contact event unless at least one body is dynamic